# How to install php plugin in intellij idea?

Tags: php, regex, cakephp, intellij-idea

I am trying to install php plugin in  intellij idea, one plugin is install successfully, and its working on controller and model, but how to connect with ctp file.

Comment: install this plugin from below Url

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=1861

Comment: no its not helpful, one plugin is install please tell me how to connect with ctp file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go to settings in intellij idea, then open file extension  for php, then add *.cyp & *.ctp , now your ctp file will be start working.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to File Tab
2. Select the Settings... option
3. Go to the Plugins  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUZHC.png)
4. Search php on the search tab then install the php extension provided by the jetbrains and restart the intellij
5. Then you will find php file or class

Comment: But not found  the PHP plug in now.

Comment: Name of extension?